# Get nearby records using lat lng with ObjectionJs and postgres, nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, objection.js

I've been googling for a while now, can't find any way to use nearby query in my locations table which looks like this:

```
id|lat|lng
```

now what I want is, I've lat and long of a location, I want to search this table using those lat long with limit of let's say 5KM.

Main Problem: I've done similar thing in mysql. but with ObjectionJs postgres involved, I don't know where to start.

Comment: With unflavored PostgreSQL, you would preferentially do this with the postgis extension. I've never heard of ObjectionJs postgres, but maybe you can use postgis there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create a raw query use this formula (objection function whereRaw()):

```sql
SELECT id, lat, lon
FROM table
WHERE 6377830.272 * acos((sin(lat*PI()/180) * sin(${lat}*PI()/180)) + cos(lat*PI()/180) * cos(${lat}*PI()/180) * cos(${lon}*PI()/180 - lon*PI()/180)) / 1000 < 5;
```

This query returns all rows within a 5 km radius.

Comment: let me check, will update you

Comment: can you also add whereRaw() example with objection.js model? I don't see any example anywhere, Please.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/find-methods.html#whereraw